# `location.state` in dependency of `useEffect` not getting triggered for the initial rendering of component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a parent component which is having `Outlet` for sub routes.

I wanted to pass the data from the parent component (`App.js`) to the component rendered by `Outlet` for the default Link (`Test.js`).

For which, I used the state object of location and passed the data from parent Component.

```
<Link to="" state={{ data }}>
  Render test
</Link>
```

Although on initial render, it is still null in child component (`Test.js`), but if I navigate to some other route (route: `/dummy`, component : `Dummy.js`) within that parent and come back to `Test.js` components route, I am able to see value in the `location.state`.

Codesandbox link for more clarity: https://codesandbox.io/s/location-state-zjs5rt

I tried adding `location.state` as dependency in `useEffect` but it is not getting triggered on the initial render.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (location.state) {
    setTestData(location.state.data);
  }
}, [location?.state]);
```

I wanted to pass some async data from `App.js` and use it inside `Test.js` component to render certain things, how can I achieve this?

Comment: First time the "Render test" link is clicked the state is passed. The sandbox you link seems to be working correctly as I'd expect. What exactly is the issue you face?

Comment: When clicked the state is getting passed, but on the initial render of App.js for that route (which btw is also rendering Test.js component for same route), is not having data. (Look at the string I am trying to print in the Test.js file)

Comment: Why would it when `Test` component is mounted? Route state is only passed during the navigation transition, i.e. when the `Link` is clicked. It sounds like you are trying to do something *other than* pass some data when a link is clicked. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Oh okay was not aware of that. If that is the case, is there any way that I can achieve this functionality of passing data from App.js to Test.js.
What I want to achieve is App.js will fetch some data from API, and it will be used in Test.js file as well, so I wanted to pass that data instead of making another request in Test component on mount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just wanting to make available some state in the `App` component to any of the nested route's `element` components then I'd suggest passing it via the React context available via the [`Outlet`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/outlet) component. The routed components use the [`useOutletContext`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-outlet-context) hook to access the context.

Example:

App

```
import { Outlet, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setData("data that comes later");
    }, 2000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {data ? (
        <>
          <h2>This is APP component</h2>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Render test</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/dummy">Another dummy component</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <Outlet context={{ data }} /> // <-- passed in context
        </>
      ) : (
        <>Loading...</>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Test

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useOutletContext } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Test(props) {
  const { data } = useOutletContext();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("data using location", data);
  }, [data]);

  return <div>This is another component "{data}"</div>;
}
```

[image: Edit location-state-in-dependency-of-useeffect-not-getting-triggered-for-the-init]